# add extra details to user on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add details like first and last name to a user once they sign up via firebase though I am having some troubles. the user seems to be getting created in the auth section, but the users node isn't getting created on the database

```
signup() {
    this.setState({
      // When waiting for the firebase server show the loading indicator.
      loading: true
    });
    // Make a call to firebase to create a new user.
    firebaseApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.state.email,
      this.state.password).then(() => {
        this.setState({
          // Clear out the fields when the user logs in and hide the progress indicator.
          email: '',
          password: '',
          loading: false
        })
        this.userFirebase.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({
          first_name: this.state.first_name,
          last_name: this.state.last_name,
        })
        NavigationActions.Venue()
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Leave the fields filled when an error occurs and hide the progress indicator.
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
      Alert.alert('Hold on to your baristas, first a few basics!', error.message );
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you step through the code, does it get to the `update()` call? If yes, are there any error messages showing in your JavaScript console?

Comment: perfect found it, was using firebase instead of firebaseApp, and also didn't have the permissions set correctly